# Как удалить ненужные ресурсы из проекта

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, forms, icon

Делаю приложение Windows Forms (.NET Framework). Добавил иконку приложению - прошло нормально. Но потом, когда я решил добавить иконку формам, VS просил меня снова выбрать иконку с диска (не предложив использовать иконку приложения), и после компиляции размер проекта вырос со 100 до 500 кБ, и что самое неприятное, что когда я удалил все иконки с форм, в надежде уменьшить проект, после компиляции проект остался 500 кБ, как будто где (мне неизвестно) эти дублирующие иконки хранятся.

Понимаю что оффтоп, но буду рад, если мне помогут присвоить НЕДУБЛИРУЮЩИЕСЯ иконки на формы из одного ресурса, чтобы один и тот же файл многократно не увеличивал размер. Но в данном посте хотя бы хотелось бы получить ответ на вопрос, как мне теперь "вычистить мусор" из проекта и удалить повторяющиеся иконки, увеличивающие объем EXE файла?

Comment: Зайдите в свойства проекта (ПКМ по названию проекта (не решения), кнопка Свойства). Там есть вкладка Ресурсы. Проверьте, есть ли там что-то

Comment: @SelfishCrawler, проверял, там ничего нет

Comment: Тогда проверьте файл в развороте формы, у меня это выглядит примерно [так](https://i.imgur.com/eq51mIe.png). Дважды щелкните по файлу resx. Там точно такие же ресурсы, как те что в проекте, только привязанные к конкретной форме. Видимо Вы добавляли свои иконки к каждой форме в этот файл .resx. А чтобы сделать один файл изображения на весь проект, нужно добавить его туда, куда я сказал выше в комментарии (в свойства проекта), и присвоить ссылки там где это необходимо.

Comment: Иконка приложения - это не-resx ресурс типа ICON, а не managed embedded resource, так что наверное никак. Так что вам придется включать иконку как минимум дважды, один раз как application icon, второй - как инконку формы.

Comment: @PashaPash дважды это мягко сказано, что делать если в приложении несколько форм, а иконка должна быть одна

Comment: @SelfishCrawler, да, Вы правы. Спасибо. Ответьте на этот вопрос, пожалуйста, чтобы я мог засчитать Вам правильный ответ

Comment: @PashaPash "Иконка приложения - это не-resx ресурс типа ICON, а не managed embedded resource" Первое *не* лишнее? Или второе?

Comment: @4per нет. ....

Comment: @PashaPash второе «не» всё же лишнее

Comment: @4per точно нет. это не managed embedded resource

Comment: @PashaPash дошло. Долго не мог прочитать предложение с двумя "не" и союзом "а"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При добавлении файлов на форму, для каждой отдельно созданной формы в Windows Forms создается соответствующий ***.resx** файл, в который данные ресурсы помещаются. Таким образом, добавляя один и тот же файл на несколько форм, Вы получаете дубликаты одного ресурса. Просмотреть ресурсы каждой формы в Visual studio можно, развернув соответствующую форму в представлении проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, для решения проблемы, необходимо удалить дубликаты из каждого такого файла ресурсов в каждой форме.

Чтобы избежать подобной проблемы, есть следующие варианты:

1. Приложить картинку к исполняемому файлу, в коде подгружать его по относительному пути.
2. Добавить картинку в общее хранилище ресурсов для проекта (ПКМ по названию проекта -> Свойства -> Ресурсы) с соответствующим названием (к примеру `MyImageResource`, а затем обратиться к нему в коде через `Properties.Resources.MyImageResource`.
3. Собственный контейнер файлов (для более крупных проектов)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы полностью избежать дублирования иконки в проекте

Перевод https://stackoverflow.com/a/16559342/5574962

1. В свойствах проекта > Приложение > Значок и манифест and Manifest > через обзор найдите файл *.ico и добавьте его.
2. В конструкторе или обработчике события `Load` каждой формы добавьте:

   ```
    this.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Application.ExecutablePath);
   ```